# Next.js Persistent component - Youtube embed that plays even after changing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

I am trying to create a Next.js react app. One of the requirements is that a youtube player must persist when changing pages. Only issue is that I'm not sure if it's possible with the way Next works. It seems that pages will aways re-mount regardless of the structure.

Here in my app I export Index into page.js which acts as a parent component.

```
<Media/> //Youtube player
```

page.js will always remount thus the player will reload.

page.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { checkLang } from '../helpers/langSupport';
import { changeLang } from '../store/actions/langAction';
import store from '../store/store';
import { Router } from '../config/router';
import Media from './youtube';
import Head from './head';
import Nav from './nav';

const childPage = (ChildPage) => {
    return (
        class Page extends React.Component {
            componentDidMount(){
                this.checkLanguage()
            }

            checkLanguage() {
                checkLang(this.props.url, (status, result) => {
                    if(status){
                        store.dispatch(changeLang(result))
                    }else{
                        Router.pushRoute('/en'+this.props.url.asPath)
                    }
                })
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <div>
                            <Head />
                            <Nav />
                            <ChildPage {...this.props} />
                            <Media/>
                        </div>
                    </Provider>
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

export default childPage;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { add, minus } from '../store/actions/countAction';
import Page from '../components/page';

export class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="hero">
          Count: {this.props.count.count}
          <br/><br/>
          <button onClick={()=>this.props.dispatch(add(1))}>Add</button>
          <button onClick={()=>this.props.dispatch(minus(1))}>Minus</button>
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
          .hero{
            margin-left: 50px;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Page(connect(state=>state)(Index));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been implemented as `_app.js`. Check out the [next.js readme](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-app) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is something that does not exist in Next.js yet. Though it is actively discussed and will probably be implemented in the near future.

`ReactDOM.render` is called on every page change, so this is not possible today.

See discussions on:

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/88
- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/2440
- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/3288